# Apache 404 Not Found error after Ubuntu update

Tags: apache, ubuntu, http-status-code-404

I have had installed separadly since more than one year Apache, Php and MySQL on my Ubuntu 12.04 (LTS). Everything worked perfectly until a couple of days ago my OS did an update and then I get that 404 Not Found error every time that I try to access one of my proyects from my /var/www directory or even the PhpMyAdmin.

I've tried a lot of things to fix this but nothing works. I change the "Allow None" to "All" on the config file, change the IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf, I even reinstalled Apache (I did it properly, first with purge and all that, and then installing the apache).

This is what my error.log file says:

[Sat Feb 18 11:45:32.863856 2014] [core:notice] [pid 4656:tid 140028861409088] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

So, what can be the problem?

Comment: try running "sudo service apache2 start"

Comment: The service starts when the computer starts... I did what you said and nothing change.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it editing the file "/etc/apache2/sites-available".
I changed the line "DocumentRoot /var/www/html" to "DocumentRoot /var/www" and restarted the service.